# How to switch from text to graphical boot menu in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bcd

Old Windows 8 way doesn't seem to work.

When I type

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy standart
```

in cmd, I get

```
The integer data is not valid as specified.
```

Comment: You misspelled `standard`

Comment: the user "fixer1234" edited what you said you wrote in the command line. And he edited it after somebody has had commented about it. So his edit made steven's comment look odd, and he potentially may have edited out the problem. But prior to fixer1234's edit, the word 'standard' was spelt differently in the question in what the questioner showed/claimed he had written on the command line

Comment: Reverted the spelling mistake in case its relevant.